# How can I get data based on id and pass data text field for editting

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Trying to edit the blog data based on blog id, but I am not able to get the blog data. I would like to display the data in the input name columns heading, tags under the `Blog data to display for edit`. Could someone please advise ?

CSB link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-turing-x8ph7k?file=/src/App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const blogListData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    heading: "React state",
    date: "20-May-2022",
    tag: "React",
    count: "3"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    heading: "Cypress testing detailss",
    date: "21-May-2022",
    tag: "Cypress",
    count: "5"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    heading: "Unix commands",
    date: "15-June-2022",
    tag: "Cypress",
    count: "2"
  }
];
export default function App() {
  const [blogList, setBlogList] = useState(blogListData);
  const [editData, setEditData] = useState([]);
  const [helperText, setHelperText] = useState("");

  const handleBlogDelete = (idx) => {
    // rest of the delete process here
  };

  const handleEditBlog = (idx) => {
    console.log("Edit record ::" + idx);
    const blogUpdateCopy = [...blogList];
    for (let blogData in blogUpdateCopy) {
      if (blogData.id === idx) {
        setEditData(blogUpdateCopy);
      }
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="blogListSection">
        <h1>Edit blogs</h1>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="editBlogSection">
            {blogList.map(({ id, heading, tag, count }) => (
              <div className="row">
                <a
                  key={id}
                  href="https://www.google.com/"
                  className="blogitems"
                >
                  <pre>
                    <span>{tag}</span>{" "}
                    {!heading && heading.length > 15
                      ? heading.substring(0, 15) + "..."
                      : heading}
                    <span>{count}</span>
                  </pre>
                </a>
                <div className="blogitems edit">
                  <button onClick={() => handleEditBlog(id)}>Edit</button>
                </div>
                <div className="blogitems delete">
                  <button onClick={() => handleBlogDelete(id)}>Delete</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
        <h1> Blog data to display for edit</h1>
        <div className="row">
          {editData.map(({ id, heading, tag }) => (
            <div key={id} className="editBlogSection">
              <input type="text" name="heading" value={heading}></input>
              <br></br>
              <input type="text" name="tags" value={tag}></input>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <label>
          <span className="adminDeleteMsg">{helperText}</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: In the `handleEditBlog` you are doing `setEditData(blogUpdateCopy)` is it correct? Or do you want to set `blogData` instead?

Comment: Yeh I assume that this part `setEditData(blogUpdateCopy)` is wrong !  I wish to set the correct `blogData` based on id

Comment: Just FYI: You are doing `for (... in ...)` which will give you indexes and not the items in the array. Instead you should use `for(... of ...)` which will give you items in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your handleEditBlog function

```
const handleEditBlog = (idx) => {
console.log("Edit record ::" + idx);
const blog  = blogData.find(item=>item.id===idx)
    setEditData(blog);
}
```

and make `editData` state as empty object `{}`;

then in the UI

```
 <div className="row">
        <div className="editBlogSection">
          <input type="text" name="heading" onChange={(e)=>onChangeValue(e.target,editData.id)} value={editData.heading}></input>
          <br></br>
          <input type="text" name="tags" onChange={(e)=>onChangeValue(e.target,editData.id)} value={editData.tag}></input>
        </div>
    </div>
```

then create `onChangeValue` function like this to update blogdata

```
const onChangeValue =(target,id)=>{
   let blogIndex = blogData.findIndex(item=>item.id===idx);
   if(blogIndex){
     let editCopy ={...editData};
     editCopy[target.name] =target.value;
     let data=[...blogData];
     data[blogIndex] = editCopy;
     setBlogList(data);
   } 
 }
```

Comment: Can I ask one question. by default if the state is having default values ..how can we pass the values during on click on edit ?

Comment: Great answer, nicely explained !

Answer (score 2):

Try this code for **handleEditBlog** method.

```js
  const handleEditBlog = (idx) => {
    const filterdata = blogList.filter((item) => item.id == idx);
    setEditData(filterdata);
  };
```

Comment: For getting single object better to use find method instead of filter, because filter returns an array.

Comment: Yes, but you have set array not object in setEditData so that's why I use filter method

Comment: You can set [{}] like this :).

Comment: If you are using find method then you can otherwise set direct array

Comment: Cool, it's not big deal both are correct sometimes for performance we can take care of it.

Comment: Yes, definitely after all it's always about your requirement and the performance of the app.

Comment: just out of curiosity, may i know which one is faster  `filter` or `find` ?

Comment: If you want first match data then find method is faster then filter.

Comment: @soccerway It's depends on requirments for getting single object find is better and faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try this change in your Edit function it will work.

```
const handleEditBlog = (idx) => {
 const currentBlog = blogList?.find((item) => item?.id === idx);
 setEditData([currentBlog]);
};
```

Hope it will work, Thanks :).

Comment: Thanks could you please tell what does this `blogList?` line meant by ?

Comment: Appreciate your reply, this is working thank you ! Upvoted and accepted !

Comment: blogList?. '?.' means it is optional chaining (similar && tye condition) and it prevent from error.